# Is it possible protect cells and ranges in google sheets after data entry using app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible protect cells and ranges in google sheets after first data entry using app script? I am new to the script game.  I use a drop down list and need to lock the cell / range data after the data change.

Comment: Possible`````````````````​`````````````````

Answer (score 1):

Using **onEdit** simple trigger (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) you can detect the modify and with methods of **Class Protection** you can lock a range of cells (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection).